# Conflicting dtypes in pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to determine the dtype of a pandas DataFrame column. The column should be of type `np.datetime64`.

However, when I try to access the dtype directly, here's what I get:

```
>>> block.asof_date.dtype
dtype('O')
```

When I print the column, I get the following:

```
>>> block.asof_date
...
990   2015-11-02
991   2015-11-02
992   2015-11-02
993   2015-11-02
994   2015-11-02
Name: asof_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

What's going on here? What is the actual datatype of the column, and how can I access it?

numpy version: 1.9.2

pandas version: 0.16.1

python version: 3.4.3

Comment: doesn't `df.info()` tell you the `dtype`?

Comment: It tells me the same thing that block.asof_date.dtype tells me - that it's of type object.

Comment: Can you post python, pandas, numpy version and code that reproduces this error, thanks